# Grafana - use a specific non-zero value as visible zero point

Tags: graph, grafana

Is there a way to define a non-zero value that will be handled as zero in the graph? So instead of starting from 0 GB, the graph would begin from 70 GB, and show that 70 GB as 0 GB? So if you have an actual value of eg. 95 GB, it would appear as (95 - 70) = 25 GB in the Y-axis?

There would never be less than 70 GB, but in that case it is OK if it shows as a negative value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is just add `-70` (or whatever the offset you need is) to your query.

The exact implementation may depend on your specific datasource (which you've not mentioned), but most databases will support math operations like that. In the Grafana query builder UI it should be under "math" in the SELECT row.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That is exactly what I needed. I added ``Math(-70000000000)`` to the select, since the actual value comes as bytes, so 70 GB = 70*10^9. Didn't know you could edit the query directly in the UI and was trying to do strange things in the config JSON :)

Comment: For others in similar situation: left-click on the header of the graph (EFS Allocation in my screenshots above), and there is an "Edit" button. Then in the tab "Metrics", there is a query you can edit. Clicking on the hamburger on the right shows "Toggle Edit Mode", where you can see the actual query (eg. SQL, or other depending on your data source).